# How to change texture material of an object created with JSONLoader on click

Tags: javascript, three.js

I am working with Three.js where I created an object. I have created some buttons and am able to change the material color ob the object by clicking on dedicated button.

***The question is:*** How can I fulfill the same process with a texture material, so if I click on the button "Texture", the material changes from color to the Texture Material I want to be on that object? Is it possible?

Here is the way the buttons are working:

```
<nav>
  <span>Choose color:</span>
  <input type="button" value="White" onClick="mesh.traverse(function(child) {if(child instanceof THREE.Mesh){ child.material.color.setHex('0xffffff');}});" />
  <input type="button" value="Black" onClick="mesh.traverse(function(child) {if(child instanceof THREE.Mesh){ child.material.color.setHex('0x2f3a4c');}});" />          
  <input type="button" value="Green" onClick="mesh.traverse(function(child) {if(child instanceof THREE.Mesh){ child.material.color.setHex('0x44cc88');}});" />
</nav>
```

This is how I create my object with JSONLoader:

```
var loader = new THREE.JSONLoader();
loader.load('models/engine_s.js',  function( geometry ) {
  mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial( {map: false, color: 0x2f3a4c}) );
  //mesh.scale.set( 10, 10, 10 );
  mesh.rotation.x = -Math.PI / 4;
  mesh.position.y = 0;
  group.add( mesh );
  scene.add( group );
});
```

I have seen some solutions which are looking like following line:

```
obj.mesh.material.uniforms.texture = THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture("textures/1.png");
obj.mesh.material.uniforms.texture.needsUpdate = true;
```

But I am not sure if its is possible to use this solution for my purpose and if it is, how this can be done.

**UPDATE:**

I have tried following code in the head of my document:

```
<script>
    function f1(){

        var loader = new THREE.ImageLoader();
        var texture = loader.load( 'images/crate.png' );
        mesh.traverse(function(child) {
            if(child instanceof THREE.Mesh){ 
                child.material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial( { map: texture} );
                child.material.needsUpdate = true;
                child.geometry.buffersNeedUpdate = true;
                child.geometry.uvsNeedUpdate = true;
            }
        });

    }
</script>
```

and call the f1() function in the body:

```
<nav>
    <span>Choose color:</span>
    <input type="button" value="White" onClick="mesh.traverse(function(child) {if(child instanceof THREE.Mesh){ child.material.color.setHex('0xffffff');}});" />
    <input type="button" value="Black" onClick="mesh.traverse(function(child) {if(child instanceof THREE.Mesh){ child.material.color.setHex('0x2f3a4c');}});" />            
    <input type="button" value="Green" onClick="mesh.traverse(function(child) {if(child instanceof THREE.Mesh){ child.material.color.setHex('0x44cc88');}});" />
    <input type="button" value="Texture" onClick="f1();" >
</nav>
```

I get following warning message *THREE.Material: 'map' parameter is undefined*. And the material of my object is turning to white.

Here is the code on [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/accneeder/Lkgk3b8z/embedded)

Comment: It would be better to put your material in a variable so you onclick could look like `onClick="materialcolor.setHex('0xffffff')"`. This way you could also simply call a function to apply your texture map on click.

Comment: my problem is I don't know how the call could look like so the texture gets mapped to the mesh,like _mesh.traverse(function(child) {if(child instanceof THREE.Mesh){ child.material.color.setHex('0x44cc88');}});_ only for the texture part. Because if I'm not wrong texture mapping is a bit different from just changing a color

Comment: Your question is a little vague and it seems like you might benefit from looking at a few more examples. Take a look the the [docs for MeshPhoneMaterial](http://threejs.org/docs/#Reference/Materials/MeshPhongMaterial). You should just need to change properties on material instances (and maybe set needsUpdate) to change material properties.

Comment: I've added an Update to my Question. Can you tell me if I am on the right way?

Comment: In your f1 method you should not need to create a new material just set the `map` parameter to `texture`. eg. `child.material.map = texture`. You should also not need to update buffers or uvs. It would be much easier to help you if you created a jsfiddle

Comment: Hey, I have changed my code and now i get no warnings, no errors but still no texture mapping aswell. I edited my question by adding a link to the code on JSFiddle

Comment: Solved this one. I thank you very much :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This one solved my problem:

```
function f1(){

        text = THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture( 'images/crate.png' );
        mesh.traverse(function(child) {
            if(child instanceof THREE.Mesh){
                //alert("works");
                child.material.map = text;
                child.material.needsUpdate = true;
                child.geometry.buffersNeedUpdate = true;
                child.geometry.uvsNeedUpdate = true;
            }
        });
       }
```

Where ***child.geometry.buffersNeedUpdate = true;*** AND ***child.geometry.uvsNeedUpdate = true;*** are necessary.